# Facebook Embed not loading in WKWebView with Custom UserAgent

Tags: ios, facebook, wkwebview

I use a WKWebView and load a html that contains a facebook embed.

`<script async="1" defer="1" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/...`

In my webView the embed is visible.

Now I set a customUserAgent at the webView:

`webView?.customUserAgent = "custom"`

And the facebook embed is not visible anymore.
Tried it with different user agents already with the same result.
Twitter embeds are still working.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Thanks and regards Patrick

Comment: Facebook is probably simply blocking this, as part of their attempts to stop any automated bots / scrapers from accessing the content this way.

Comment: But I tried as well from Safari on a Mac with same customer user agent. And it worked.

Comment: Then the User Agent is probably not the _only_ criterion they are checking.